# ¿Cómo añadir un fichero help a una app con tkinter y python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

He buscado en la Web tanto en español como en inglés y no he encontrado nada sobre el tema.

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación con Python y Tkinter en la que he añadido la opcion "Ayuda" en un menú top level. Mi idea es poder mostrar un PDF de ayuda cuando el usuario lo desee. Imagino poder salirme sin demasiados problemas, pero tal vez hay otras opciones.

¿Podeis, por favor, indicarme como hacerlo de manera elegante y pythonica?.

Comment: ¿Como estás pensando mostrar el PDF? Si quieres mostrar el texto del PDF puedes parsearlo con alguna libreria

Comment: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.pdfviewer.html

Comment: sin embargo se basa en [wx](http://www.wxpython.org/) no en Tk.

Comment: además  mira en http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653929/pdf-viewer-for-python-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Un buen ejemplo lo tienes en el editor [Idle](https://docs.python.org/library/idle.html) que lleva (*casi*) toda instalación de python. La ayuda de este editor muestra simplemente un fichero html renderizado con el motor `HTMLParser` de la librería estándar, sin necesidad de instalar nada más.

Creo que puedes reutilizar directamente el fichero [help.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Lib/idlelib/help.py) de Idle, aunque es mejor que te mires el resto del [código de la aplicación](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Lib/idlelib) por si te sirve de inspiración.

Puedes probar con:

```
from idlelib.idle_test.htest import run
from idlelib.help import show_idlehelp

run(show_idlehelp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar adjuntar el archivo de ayuda en *PDF* en la misma carpeta del ejecutable principal de tu programa y crear una función (para la opción *command* al seleccionar la opción *Ayuda* en la cascada) que llame al lector de *PDF* de tu sistema operativo, es decir, utilizar la línea de comandos del sistema operativo pero llamado desde *Python*, cuyo comando es *shell*, en consonancia con la ruta de acceso al archivo de ayuda en *PDF*.

Comment: Hola @Luis. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por el aporte. Quizás tu respuesta se podría beneficiar con un ejemplo práctico. ¿Podrías mostrar un fragmento de código de cómo se implementaría? La idea del sitio es aportar contenido con la mayor calidad posible